# cadastro de alunos

Tags: python

Fiz o Seguinte codigo para cadastro de aluno:

```
laluno=[] 
lemail=[]
lcurso=[]
todos =[laluno,lcurso,lemail]


def menu():
    print("Menu\n[1]Cadastrar novo aluno\n[2]Lista de alunos cadastrados\n[3]Buscar aluno\n[4]Remover Aluno\n[5]Atualizar o nome do Aluno\n[6]Salvar Arquivo\n[0]Sair ")
    opt= int(input("Escolha uma opção:"))
    return opt

def add():
    aluno=str(input("Digite o nome do Aluno:"))
    if aluno in laluno:
        print("O Aluno já consta na lista!")
    else:

        laluno.append(aluno)
        curso=str(input("Digite o curso:"))
        email=str(input("Digite o email:"))
        lcurso.append(curso)
        lemail.append(email)
        print("Aluno cadastrado com sucesso!")
    pass 


def ver_td():
    print(todos)
    pass


def pesquisa():
    aluno=str(input("Digite o nome do aluno:"))
    if aluno in laluno:
        print(laluno)
    else:
        print("O nome não se encontra na lista. Tente novamente!")
    pass 

def remover():
    aluno=str(input("Digite o nome do aluno:"))
    if aluno in laluno:
        laluno.remove(aluno)
        print("Aluno removido com sucesso!")

    else:
        print("Aluno não encontrado. Tente novamente!")

    pass

def edit():
    aluno=str(input("Digite o nome do Aluno que deseja alterar:"))
    if aluno in laluno:
        laluno.remove(aluno)
        aluno=str(input("Digite o nome do novo aluno"))
        laluno.append(aluno)
        ask=str(input("Deseja alterar Curso e Email Também? [S/N]"))
        if ask == "Ss":
            curso=str(input("Digite o nome do curso que deseja alterar:"))
            lcurso.remove(curso)
            curso=str(input("Digite o nome do novo curso:"))
            lcurso.append(curso)
            email=str(input("Digite o email que deseja alterar:"))
            lemail.remove(email)
            email=str(input("Digite um novo email"))
            lemail.append(email)
            print("Alterações feitas com sucesso")
        else:
            print("Nome alterado com sucesso!")
def salvar():
    save=str(input("Deseja salvar arquivo? [S/N]"))
    if save == "Ss":
        arquivoName=str(input("Digite o nome do arquivo:"))
        for i in arquivoName:
            arquivo=open(arquivoName,"w")
            arquivo.write(str(i))
        arquivo.close()
    else:
        print("Obrigado por utilizar nosso sistema!")

    pass


opcao = menu()
while True:
    if opcao == "1":
        add()
    elif opcao == "2":
        ver_td()
    elif opcao == "3":
        pesquisa()
    elif opcao == "4":
        remover()
    elif opcao == "5":
        edit()
    elif opcao == "6":
        salvar()

    elif opcao == "0":
        print("Obrigado por utilizar um de nossos serviços.")
    break
```

Só que o erro está sendo que não acontece nada, digito uma opção e o programa finaliza. E mesmo tirando o BREAK no final, o programa continua em execução, só que não faz nenhuma ação.

Comment: você está comparando inteiros com strings

Comment: @igorroberto A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la?  Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 6):

Você está cometendo um pequeno erro. Observe sua linha:

```
opt= int(input("Escolha uma opção:"))
```

Você está convertendo a entrada para um tipo númerico inteiro (`int`)
Porém está verificando a igualdade dos valores com `string`, observe:

```
opcao = menu()
while True:
    if opcao == "1":
        add()
    elif opcao == "2":
        ver_td()
    elif opcao == "3":
        pesquisa()
    elif opcao == "4":
        remover()
    elif opcao == "5":
        edit()
    elif opcao == "6":
        salvar()

    elif opcao == "0":
        print("Obrigado por utilizar um de nossos serviços.")
    break
```

Uma forma de corrigir é remover as aspas duplas da igualdade:

```
opcao = menu()
while True:
    if opcao == 1:
        add()
    elif opcao == 2:
        ver_td()
    elif opcao == 3:
        pesquisa()
    elif opcao == 4:
        remover()
    elif opcao == 5:
        edit()
    elif opcao == 6:
        salvar()

    elif opcao == 0:
        print("Obrigado por utilizar um de nossos serviços.")
    break
```

Outra forma é deixar o while como está, ou seja, verificação da igualdade dos valores com `string` ( ex: `if opcao == "1":`) e remover a conversão para `int` do `input`,após modificação deverá ficar assim:

```
opt= input("Escolha uma opção:")
```

Comment: Outra forma de corrigir é só tratar como strings mesmo: `opt = input("Escolha uma opção:")`. Assim, até evita um erro quando o usuário digitar um valor não numérico, aí é só tratar quando não encaixar em nenhum dos elses.

Comment: @CypherPotato verdade, aconselha incluir esta forma na resposta?

Comment: seria interessante :)

Comment: Vdd, como não vi isso antes. mt obg